Saving a record using generateClient from amplify in mutation function
I'm using the Gen 2 amplify config and I have created a schema with the following model
export const NewsletterMail = a
  .model({
    id: a.string(),
    email: a.email().required(),
    confirmed: a.boolean().default(false),
  })
  .identifier(["email"])
  .authorization((allow) => [allow.publicApiKey()]);

Now I've also added a mutation handler function in where I call an external api to send the email (which works just fine), but I want to first save the email in the model above.
How is this done?
I've tried by adding the generateClient this into the handler function:
import amplifyConfig from "../../../amplify_outputs.json";
...
export const handler = async (event) => {
  Amplify.configure(amplifyConfig);
  const client = generateClient<Schema>();

  const emailCreatedResponse = await client.models.NewsletterMail.create({
    email: event.arguments.email,
  });
... send email api logic ...
}

But since the amplify_outputs are generated, it only works on local with the generated amplify_outputs it does not work when deployed.
Any suggestion on how to pass the generated amplify_outputs.json on deploy to the function?
